# Unable to (manually) load cifar10 dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

First, I tried to load using:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()
```

But it gave an error:

```
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz: None -- [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1125)
```

So I manually downloaded the dataset and put it in `C:\Users\SAHAN\.keras\datasets` and renamed it to `cifar-10-batches-py.tar.gz`.

But then it gives an error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\SAHAN\\.keras\\datasets\\cifar-10-batches-py.tar.gz'
```

How can I load this dataset?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I was having a similar **CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED** error downloading CIFAR-10. Putting this in my python file worked:

```py
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Reference: https://programmerah.com/python-error-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-has-expired-40374/

Answer (score 1):

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

This Error is due to Secure Socket Layer (SSL) certificate, we can resolve this with the help of the above line of code. This works for me !!